# How to filter most recently created pdas of a program

Tags: pda, spl-token-program, spl, associated-token-account

How to filter most recently created pdas of a program, How should date be store in pda data so that we can directly filter based on the data stored in pda. For ex. filtering all pda of a program created in last 2 days.

Fetching all pda and then filter out is too heavy operation, as number of pda increases. so want to directly fetch pda based on the data stored in them.